# gtk_init hangs in a thread

Tags: c++, gtk

I have a c++ app that has to create a gtk based popup on certain event.
Currently, I fork a thread on that event called `_displaytask` and that thread calls `gtk_init()`.
The call to `gtk_init` hangs and never returns. Anyone knows here as to why the call hangs?
The gtk version is gtk+-2.0.

```
void* Gui::displayTask(void *data)
{
    IDC_TRACE("Gui::display task tart");
    Gui* obj=(Gui *)data;
    if(obj!=NULL)
    {    
        if( ! g_thread_supported() )
            g_thread_init( NULL );

        /* Secure gtk */
        gdk_threads_init();
            gdk_threads_enter();
        IDC_TRACE("doing a gtk init");        
        gtk_init_check(0,0);
        obj->initialise();
```

The control reaches `gtk_init()` but never gets past it to reach initialise.

Comment: Generally `gtk_init` and `gtk_main` should be called from the `main` thread.

Comment: Tried that...Still hangs.Actually the main thread(process) is a server.It's got the CORBA actor concept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gui_display:04714807269964847148072699648
errno variable  =  0

(process:26070): Gtk-WARNING **: This process is currently running setuid or setgid.
This is not a supported use of GTK+. You must create a helper
program instead. For further details, see:

```
http://www.gtk.org/setuid.html
```

Refusing to initialize GTK+.

I did not know this earlier.Got this error message.Now, the only way to do it would be in a different process

Answer (score 0):

http://www.bassi.io/articles/2014/08/27/gdk-and-threads/

Your order is wrong.

Should be:

```
enter
init
main
leave
```